# didReceiveRemoteNotification Not Being Called Unless Application Resumed From Notification

Tags: ios, swift2

the title explains whats happening. the application is running but minimised.the notification is shown to the user. when the user taps on the notification, the application is brought to foreground and the method didReceiveRemoteNotification is entered. however, if the user clicks on the app icon instead to resume the app, the method didReceiveRemoteNotification is not executing.

here is my code:

in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
 //FOR ALLOWING NOTIFICATIONS
            let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()

 func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
        let deviceTokenStr = convertDeviceTokenToString(deviceToken)
        GlobalVariables.UserDefaults.setValue(deviceTokenStr,forKey: "Push_Notification_Reg_ID");
        RZLog.VIP("The PushNotification Device Token is: \(deviceTokenStr)")

    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {

        RZLog.Error(error.description)
    }

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        RZLog.Debug("A NEW NOTIFICATION HAS BEEN RECEIVED")
        //handle

                completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NoData)
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is in the payload of your notification?  Does it have `content-available:` ?

Comment: i just added "content-available":"1", lol and it worked. but now its being called twice in case i pressed on the notification

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. The method is called when a remote notification is received in the app (while in background or foreground) and also when the user launches the app from a notification.

If the user taps on an app icon, only

```
applicationWillEnterForeground:
```

and

```
applicationDidBecomeActive:
```

will be called

Answer (score -1):

in Background didReceiveRemoteNotification will not be called. You should use

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {

    if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive) {

    NSLog(@"Inactive");

    //Show the view with the content of the push

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);

} else if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground) {

    NSLog(@"Background");

    //Refresh the local model

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);

} else {

    NSLog(@"Active");

    //Show an in-app banner

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);

}
}
```

Basically didReceiveRemoteNotification is only called in the following Scenarios:

1. Tap on the push notification banner & app comes to foreground and didReceiveRemoteNotification is called.
2. While App is running in foreground, push notification arrives & didReceiveRemoteNotification is called.

From Apple documentation:
If the app is not running when a push notification arrives, the method launches the app and provides the appropriate information in the launch options dictionary. The app does not call this method to handle that push notification. Instead, your implementation of the application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions: or application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method needs to get the push notification payload data and respond appropriately.